# Transferring list to a difficult hierarchical dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Everybody, hello,

I have a task to transfer list like `random_list=['2018-01-01', 'google', 'cpc', 100]` (which could be expanded manually) into dictionary like `{'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': 100}}}`, which is also could be expanded more, if the list is expanded.

For example, if I would add any string or int in list - it should be included in dictionary and be like `{'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': {100: 'example'}}}}`, or `{'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': {'example': 100}}}}`.

I've travelled a lot on this stack overflow website, and there are questions like that, but nothing compared to "included dictionary". I'm a new user here, and maybe in future my skills of searching here will be upgraded, but I can't find anything similar. I can transform it into a simple dictionaries, but nothing compared to that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem did you encounter in solving this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by recursion, using the first entry in the list as a key to a value which is a nested dictionary created from the rest of the list:

```
def make_dict(l):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return None
    elif len(l) == 2:
        return { l[0] : l[1] }
    else: 
        return { l[0] : make_dict(l[1:]) }

print(make_dict(['2018-01-01', 'google', 'cpc', 100]))
print(make_dict(['2018-01-01', 'google', 'cpc', 100, 'example']))
```

Output:

```
{'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': 100}}}
{'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': {100: 'example'}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also build it using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

random_list=['2018-01-01', 'google', 'cpc', 100]

reduce(lambda v, k: {k:v}, reversed(random_list[:-1]), random_list[-1])
# {'2018-01-01': {'google': {'cpc': 100}}}
```

We start with the initial value `random_list[-1]` (100), which will be passed as value when we start iterating backward on the rest of the list. On the first iteration, the dict `{'cpc': 100}` gets built. 
On each following iteration, the already built dict gets passed as value to build the next level of the dict.